# Have I correctly solved this RLC problem?

Tags: passive-networks, homework, laplace-transform

[image]

**Now I needed to find the transfer function as well as impulse response**
$$\\ R=14\Omega \\ L=2H \\ \\ C=\frac{1}{12}F \\ In \ s-domain \\ R=14\Omega \\ L=sL=s\cdot 2=2s \\ \\ C=\frac{1}{sC}=\frac{1}{s\cdot \frac{1}{12}}=\frac{12}{s} \\ H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=\frac{L+C}{R+L+C}=\frac{2s+\frac{12}{s}}{14+2s+\frac{12}{2}}=\frac{2s^{2}+12}{2s^{2}+14s+12} \\ L^{-1}[\frac{2s^{2}+12}{2s^{2}+14s+12}]=\delta (t)+\frac{7}{5}e^{-t}-\frac{42}{5}e^{-6t}$$

Comment: Hi Stormy,  homework questions require an attempt to solve or they will be closed.

Comment: I think you should have simplified your transfer function. Both numerator and denominator are obviously divisible evenly by 2. Not sure about your inverse, off hand.

Comment: Yes, the final answer is correct, but \$\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=\frac {L+C}{R+L+C}\$ Is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean @Chu? Is the representation wrong or the transfer function itself

Comment: \$(L+C)/(L+C+R)\$ is meaningless.

Comment: @stormy I think Chu meant you should use (Z_L +Z_C)/(Z_L +Z_C+R). The way you wrote it can lead you to use the raw inductance and capacitance instead of the impedances by mistake.